# Understanding properties by writing own setter method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

So I'm having trouble with OOAD, properties, the self keyword, etc.  I wanted to just create a simple test project that has a UITableView.  I have an ivar of

```
NSArray *tableData;
```

how would I write a setter and getter method for this?  I thought my setter would look like:

```
- (void)setTableData:(NSArray *)array {
    [tableData autorelease];
    tableData = [array retain];
}
```

Then when I try to use this method in my viewDidLoad, I realize that I need to create an instance of my ViewController.  This seems like what not to do when I look at how it's done in books where they create a property for the NSArray, then in viewDidLoad just do a

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
    self.tableData = array;
[array release];
```

I'm kind of just trying to understand what goes on behind the scenes, to try to understand OOAD principles, ivars, properties, self, etc.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you try to use the `setTableData:` method within `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you already know that using `@synthesize` will create setter/getter methods for you, but it's good to know what's going on "under the hood" to understand the concepts.

As far as a setter method goes, you're probably better off with something like this:

```
- (void)setTableData:(NSArray *)array {
    if (tableData != array) {
        [tableData release];
        tableData = [array retain];
    }
}
```

This basically checks to make sure the new array is actually different than the current.  If it is, it releases the old instance and sets the new one.

For a getter method, just use:

```
- (NSArray *)tableData (
    return tableData;
}
```

This can be accessed by calling `self.tableData`.  And of course setting the array is done just as you have done, with `self.tableData = array`;

I hope that helps.  If you need more information, just say so and I'll be happy to try and explain further

Comment: Yes that helps, except for the using it part.  When I try to do self.tableData, I get the error of Property tableData not found.  I guess that's where my confusion was cause then I thought I had to create a property to use the self keyword.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You need to set a property in your header file.  You already have `NSArray *tableData` delared, I'm sure.  But you also have to declare `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tableData` at the bottom of your header file, where you'd declare methods.  Then you can use your setter and getter methods

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh.  Yes!  I keep thinking a property immediately means synthesize, but it's only the synthesize that creates the getter/setter methods.  So what's the difference if an ivar is a property and when it's not?

Comment: Aa property lets you assign values to the ivar, as well as let you specify how it acts. For example, you could have `@property (readwrite)` or `(readonly)` or `(nonatomic, assign)` or `(retain)`, etc.  You have much greater control how the ivar is stored and retrieved, especially when using your setter/getter methods. A regular ivar, however, has a standard, non-modifiable behavior. Thus what you see is what you get. `@property` declarations also allow you to set and get the variable from outside the code (assuming you have an outlet), which is VERY nice to have, especially in iOS